# Display list of values on ImageButton click

Tags: android

I have a Menu button image and onclick of that ImageView i have to create a list of values. Ex: In music player application onclick on menu image delete,sharevia,etc.. options are getting displayed. Kindly reply to this ASAP if anyone worked on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then all you need to do is put the values you want to display in the list in an **ArrayList** and when the ImageButton is clicked, you set this ArrayList to the **adapter** of the list and *redraw the list* by `invalidate()` or maybe just call `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

This [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) helps you to understand ListViews and in addition to this, you just need to call invalidate() or notifyDatasetChanged() in the onClickHandler.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Swayam. Thanks for your reply. Actually i don't have a list already. On click of the image button I have to create a list and need to append two values. So how can i create a ListView inside setOnClickListener(). It would be helpful if you reply with some examples if you have with you. Thanks

Comment: No actually, you can create the list in the starting only. Append the values and keep it ready and as soon as the button is clicked, you just refresh the list and show the items

Comment: fine. Let me give a try! :) Thanks again!

Comment: I saw the edit in your previous comment just now. Do you still need examples ? And again, the ListView does not need to be created inside the onClickListener.

Comment: If you have examples or any links kindly share with me.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Added a great tutorial for ListView. Hope that helps you. :)

Comment: Hi Swayam, the examples are good but I haven't get what I need exactly from that. I will try to find a solution for my issue. Anyway thanks a lot for your valuable answers.

Comment: You are welcome my friend! The tutorial was to help you with ListViews in case you weren't familiar with them. Can you please tell me what problem are you facing right now ?

Comment: yes i'm explaining you. I have a menu button in right top corner. When i click that view i need to show two list values to the user. After that user can select any of those values and the flow goes based on the user selection. So in 'setOnClickListener' method of that how to display list values? Hope i have explained you clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your problem. I have one question for you though. Why are you using a ListView to do this ? The scenario that you explained can also be done using a Dialog box and I guess that will be a much better option than this, if your options will always be the same. Display the dialogBox when the image is clicked and then in the dialog box go to the respective intent on the click.

Comment: hey this option seems to be good. Let me give a try! cool buddy it worked fine. But now another problem, i have placed the menu button on the top right corner using the class View(getLayoutInflater()). Onclick listener is not working when i clicked exactly on the menu image?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able to understand your problem. I think you should make a new question and paste your code there. Give me the link here and I will surely try to help you. :)

Comment: thanks dude! i tried yesterday and got a solution for my problem! have a nice day!

Comment: You are welcome my friend! Please do accept it as the answer so that it might help other codes facing the same problem! Cheers! :)